# Change view depending on properties collection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm building a calendar application using Ember.js and have run into some trouble.
[image]

This is what the column template looks like:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='instructor/lessons'>
  <div class='planning-column'>
    {{#each}}
      {{render 'lesson' this}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

This is what the lesson template looks like:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='lesson'>
  <div class='lesson' {{bind-attr style='style'}}>
    <div class='lesson-content'>
      <div class='lesson-time'>{{start_time}}</div>
      {{student}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Thing is: some events (lessons) overlap. I want to adjust the width of an event when it's overlapping with another event, just like Google Calendar does. Where should I detect if events overlap? Should I create an App.LessonView for that purpose? How can I iterate over the array of events from within such a view? Am I looking at this all wrong perhaps?

Comment: what do you mean by overlapping of events..do you mean bubbling???

Comment: In the last column there are several events on top of eachother. I want them to be placed side by side in the same column.